# Metamask not connecting with remix ide

Tags: remix, metamask

I have created a contract in **Remix IDE** which is provided by **zama.ai**. After creating the contract I have compiled the contract successfully and connected it to metamask but when I am going to deploy the contract it shows that "**can't detect network**".

I am using zama token on the zama network which is basically a kind of test ethereum provided by the company zama.

It always shows a buffering animation beside the account tab in Remix. I am unable to identify what the issue is, please help me out.

[image]